# UIButton label text automatically underlined by iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I am facing a strange problem.
In Storyboard and when running on device I see four `UIButton`s displayed like this:

[image]

But I have some users sending me screenshots where the text in those buttons is underlined:
[image]

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: See also [Some texts automatically underlined in iPhone 5 with iOS 7 1](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/124277) on Apple.SE